# onListItemClick and onItemLongClick Google TV

Tags: android, google-tv

Both the methods are being called when I do a long click on Google TV, but only the appropriate one is called with the same code on a tablet.  Any ideas how to handle onItemLongClick without triggering onListItemClick on GoogleTV?

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onListItemClick");
        WeatherData.getSingleton(getActivity().getApplication()).setCurrentLocationCode(WeatherData.getSingleton(getActivity().getApplication()).getLocCodes().get(position));
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int pos, long id) {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onItemLongClick");
        if (WeatherData.getSingleton(getActivity().getApplication()).getLocCodes().size() > 1)
            showDeleteAlertDialog(pos);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set return value of onItemLongClick to true so that it consumes the entire action.  Works like a charm!